# Perl DBM::Deep - add/delete in an arrayref of hashrefs

Tags: perl

I've been working with DBM::Deep and so far, it's been easy to Read and Update the keys in the DB but when it comes to adding or deleting entities it gets a little complicated and I can't see how it could be done.

I've imported an XML file with XML::Hash and then copied on a DBM::Deep object. So the result is somehow complicated ... The objective of course is to be able to recreate the XML file easily.

So this code:

```
use DBM::Deep;
use List::Util qw(first);
use Data::Dumper;

my $db = DBM::Deep->new('foo.db');
my $devices = $db->{foo}->{devices}->{device};

(my $match) = grep { $_->{hostname} eq 'myfoo' } @$devices;

print Dumper ($match);
print Dumper($devices);
```

Gives the following output for the first print:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'enable' => '0',
             'hostname' => 'myfoo',
             'auth' => 'myauth',
             'ip' => 'myip',
             'protocol' => 'ssh'
           }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' );
```

The second print shows:

```
$VAR1 = bless( [
             bless( {
                      'enable' => '0',
                      'hostname' => 'myfoo',
                      'auth' => 'myauth',
                      'ip' => 'myip',
                      'protocol' => 'ssh'
                    }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' ),
             bless( {
                      'ip' => 'myotherip',
                      'hostname' => 'myotherfoo',
                      'auth' => 'myauth',
                      'protocol' => 'telnet'
                    }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' ),
```

and so on.

Can someone please help me to understand how to Create and Delete in this data structure?

Comment: Missing semicolon before `print`.

Comment: true. fixed in the post

Comment: Doesn't [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice), [push](http://p3rl.org/push), [pop](http://p3rl.org/pop), [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift), and [unshift](http://p3rl.org/unshift) work on the dereferenced array?

Comment: Well if it does, it didn't get it ...

Comment: It seems `pop @$devices` works, as does `spice @$devices, 1, 1`, but `shift` and `splice @$devices, 0, 1` don't work...

Comment: But only when $match exists. Seems like weak references somewhere?

Comment: So I should use splice then, the next challenge is to get the index of the hashref in the arrayref

Comment: Maybe you need a different structure? A hash keyed by the hostname?

Comment: Yes I'm trying hard not to change the structure but maybe it would be worth it.

Comment: It looks like List::Moreutils "first_index" function is quite an ally. Thank you @choroba !

Comment: If the arrays aren't huge, it's probably fast enough anyway.

Comment: Around a 1000 elements. Btw since we're talking about arrays, should I splice to insert an element or use (push / unsfhit) ? The order of the array doesn't matter. I'm only using DBM::Deep for it's concurrent access feature.

Comment: Benchmark if you want to know more :-)

Comment: oh so the difference is only a matter of performance ?

Comment: Well, splice is probably less readable.

Comment: 1) The code you posted doesn't produce the output you claim it does. Could you fix the code in your question. 2) You state what output you got, but you didn't state what output you were trying to optian. Could you fix your question so it actually asks a question?